# Overlapping circular bearing distributions on a plane

Tags: python, likelihood, circular-statistics

I have some directional hydrophones capable of recognizing transient signals/sound and estimating the circular probability density function of the bearing, or direction, that the sound came from. I would like to make a probability map that shows the overlap of these distributions, which would ideally help localize where the sound is coming from. Specifically, I want the map defined such that I can get a probability value from any bounding box drawn within the map.

Here's what I have for the data. The bounds of the map itself are defined large enough such that a sound originating outside of the map would effectively have a probability of 0. Each hydrophone has a location (x, y) in the map and there can be 1 up to N hydrophones. The probability density functions are estimated from an array of bearing values calculated from the directional channels of the audio data. In the end, these distributions might look like a von Mises or wrapped normal distribution.

So far, I have tried making the map the following way. First, for every hydrophone involved, I split the estimated PDF into sectors of even spacing (e.g., 360 sectors, each with a width of 1 degree). Then, I create a grid mesh of points in the map area (more points gives higher resolution). Each point is then assigned a value based on which sector it falls into for each hydrophone. For example, if point $P_1$ falls into the sector $S_n$ of hydrophone $H_1$, the value assigned is probability between bounds defined by the sector:

$$
\int_a^b f_X(x)dx
$$

Where $f_X(x)$ is the PDF of $H_1$ and $a$ and $b$ are the bounds with respect to $S_n$. If there are multiple hydrophones, I assign the value of $P_1$ as the product of those integrals for each sector that $P_1$ falls into, where there is only one sector per hydrophone that $P_1$ can fall into. In the end, this might give a result like this:

[image]

The white dots show the hydrophone locations, the black X is the sound source location, and the red dot is the predicted location, based on the maximum point value. From here, I divide each point by the result of the double integral of this map so that the double integral goes to 1.0. With that the double integrals of drawn bounding boxes are the probability of the sound coming from that bounding box.

My question is, is this procedure sufficient in defining the probability map? Or, in the way that it is described, would the double integral of the bounding box really be the probability of the sound originating from that box?

Comment: You cannot draw a probability map without first postulating a prior probability for the location of the source (and then applying Bayes' Theorem).  It sounds like you are trying to compute a *likelihood* function for the source.  That looks like a straightforward computation based on the four circular probability densities you start with.  It also implies you do not need to normalize the result (which is tantamount to adopting some kind of "improper prior," which might or might not be meaningful or appropriate in your application).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is (a) assuming a decay of probability inversely proportional to distance from the sensor and (b) adopting a uniform prior distribution for the source location.

Unwrapping this will help you improve the procedure and tailor it to your situation.

---

It sounds like that when the orientation of the vector from a sensor the source is $\theta,$ the sensor gives you a *probability density* (per unit angle) for the source -- but it tells you nothing about the possible distance to the source.

This functions like an "improper" distribution.  In polar $(\rho,\theta)$ coordinates relative to the sensor, let the density be $f(\rho,\theta) = p(\theta),$ a function of the angle only.  Modeling all possible locations as the Euclidean plane, this density has an infinite integral.  But, more realistically, if we were to limit the range of the sensor or to work on a spherical model of the Earth, this function $p$ when suitably normalized would be a valid density.

We can work with that.  Assuming each sensor gives an independent response, its (additive) contribution to the log likelihood is the log of that normalization constant (which might vary by sensor) plus the logarithm of $p.$  Consequently, consider sensors $i=1,2,3,\ldots$ responding with probability density functions given $p_i$ and located at (Euclidean) coordinates $(x_i,y_i).$  For a source at unknown location $(\xi,\eta),$ the log likelihood of the observations is (up to an additive constant) given by

$$\Lambda(\xi,\eta) = \sum_{i} \log p_i\left(\arctan\left(\frac{\eta - y_i}{\xi - x_i}\right)\right).$$

*This* is what you should be computing to construct your "likelihood surface."

Next, if you have a prior probability distribution given by a density $g(\xi,\eta)$ for the source, the log posterior distribution is

$$\log h(\xi,\eta) = \log g(\xi,\eta) + \Lambda(\xi,\eta).$$

The density $h$ *will,*  when normalized to integrate to unity, give a valid probability density.  You might consider plotting it, perhaps limiting the plot to the central $95\%$ of all points.  (These are all points on the map with a density exceeding some threshold $t$ where $t$ satisfies $\int_{h \ge t} h(\xi,\eta)\,\mathrm d\xi\mathrm d\eta = 95/100.$  When you plot the densities on a regular grid, $t$ is found at the point where the cumulative sum of the sorted values of $h$ first exceeds $(100-95)/100\%$ of the overall sum on the grid, assuming the grid covers essentially all the probability.)

---

Here is an example.  I have numbered your sensor locations from left to right.  I suppose their responses are Fisher-Von Mises distributions centered at the true source orientation with parameters $\kappa_i=2,4,8,16.$  (Larger values of $\kappa$ are more precise.)  The source is at the "X" (which I have placed at the origin of these coordinates).

[image]

The plot of the likelihood is limited to the $95\%$ confidence region based on the likelihood ratio test: this is where you would infer the source lies, assuming nothing about any prior probabilities.

For a prior distribution (which could be anything) I use a bivariate Normal distribution centered at $(-5,5)$ and plot the densities contributing 95% of all the probability.  The resulting posterior distribution is also plotted to show 95% of the probability.  You can see how the sensor readings, through the likelihood, have modified the prior distribution to produce the kind of map at the right you seem to want.

[image]

If you use a very diffuse prior, such as a uniform distribution throughout the entire area of interest, the posterior map will look exactly like the likelihood map and (when normalized) can still be interpreted as a posterior distribution.